# get data back from a flex resultevent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

Sorry if I have opened another question but the previous answer are generic and completely wrong. Maybe I can't explain my problem as well than now I write what I want in java and maybe someone can write a WORKING and COMPLETE example in actionscript.
Than I always worked with multi-tier (web)application written in java; follow a little example of what I mean:

suppose that I have a controller class like this

```
..
public void getData() {  // suppose it respond to a button click event
Service s = new Service();
List<PeopleDTO> list = new ArrayList<PeopleDTO>();
list = s.getData();  // I need data here!! not in another method, because this is the method linked to the button
..
}
```

A Service class like this

```
..
public ArrayList<peopleDTO> getData() {
PeopleDAO dao = new PeopleDAO();
return dao.getData();
}
..
```

A PeopleDAO class like this

```
..
public ArrayList<PeopleDTO> getData() {
ArrayList<PepleDTO> arr = new ArrayList<PeopleDTO>();
PeopleDTO p = new PeopleDTO("name","surname");
arr.add(p);
return arr;
}
..
```

And a bean class PeopleDTO with two attribute (name,surname) and a constructor with both two parameters.

Than I want to do the SAME thing in actionscript.I have a flex (4.6) - Java(BlazeDS) project and THE PROBLEM IS JUST HOW GET BACK THE RESULT FROM ResultEvent. Can someone post a WORKING and COMPLETE (not a post with a method that I don't know where I have to put and what damn it does) example?? Sorry for this but I never seen actionscript before and I need dummies example. Please don't erase this post maybe delete the other one that is pointless because the answer doesn't work (at least in my case). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flex is event driven and sometimes similar to Java Swing rather than J2EE. If you want to get the data from ResultEvent.

```
private function getCountriesResult(evt:ResultEvent):void {
                var countries:ArrayCollection = evt.result as ArrayCollection;
}
```

In anycase you want to do the MVC style application, you can try out the Flex frameworks like Parsely and others.